# how to create multiple wan connection to single lan?

Tags: iptables, routing, ping, dsl, adsl

I am trying to have 2 connections simultaneously using DSL, my topolog is has given below: 
 My LAN and WAN PCs are ubuntu 14.04 virtual machines running on 2 different Windows PCs.

```
    LAN-eth1(192.168.168.0/24)------DUT ---nas1.2 ---------eth1.2(192.168.2.0/24) WAN1
                                        ---nas5.5 ---------eth1.5(192.168.5.0/24)  WAN2 

    LAN route : 
        192.168.0.0/16 gw 192.168.168.53
    DUT Route:
       192.168.168.0/24 dev eth1 
       192.168.2.0/24 dev nas1.2 
       192.168.5.0/24 dev nas5.5 
    WAN Route: 
       192.168.168.53/32 gw 192.168.2.53 
       192.168.168.53/32 gw 192.168.5.53
```

In the above set up only 192.168.5.1 LAN-TO WAN ping happens but 192.168.2.1 ping fails . If i do tcpdump, I can see packets reaching 192.168.2.1 but eth1.2 interface does not reply to the ping requests.

Following are my observations:

192.168.168.54 LAN interface IP 
 192.168.168.53 DUT LAN side IP  ping works fine on LAN side.
 192.168.2.53 WAN ip on nas1.2 wan interface eth1.2 vlan2 ip 192.168.2.1 ping from DUT works 
 192.168.5.53 WAN nas5.5 IP 192.168.5.53 , wan interface eth1.5 Ip 192.168.5.1 , ping from DUT works.

Could you please suggest some idea to make this topology work.

```
    Stage 2:
```

Its just normal bridged PVC and my wan IPs are Vlan interfaces of eth1.2 and eth1.5, I have have one lan PC, I was trying to ping both wan Ips from lan but only one wan Ip i was able to ping not both . but after enabling the ip forwarding, i can able to ping

```
    # sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
    net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0
```

But the problem is I have 2 wan IPs and both are on different PVC, When I ping both IPs from from LAN, one of the nas1.2 interface receive both pvc traffic, I am get shock how is this possible . Could you please help.. Please let me know if any further info need to for identification.